# Ошибка FOREIGN KEY constraint failed при использовании Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

Не могу понять нюанс работы с Room. Добавление в базу данных связанных через внешний ключ записей получается только так:

```
int id = (int) database.userDao().insert(user);
Position position = new Position();
position.setUserId(id);
position.setName("programmer");
database.positionDao().insert(position);
```

Хотя в примерах достаточно так:

```
database.userDao().insert(user);
database.positionDao().insert(position);
```

Во втором варианте у меня возникает ошибка FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787).
Аннотации настроены:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(
        entity = User.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "userId",
        onDelete = CASCADE)}, indices = {@Index(value = "userId")})
public class Position {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private int userId;
    private String name;
...
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isLogged;
...
}
```

Comment: Юзера код тоже в вопрос добавьте пожалуйста. Но скорее всего у Вас там тоже автогенерация id, которая и вызывает проблемы

Comment: Добавил. Действительно, есть автогенерация id.

Comment: Как вариант решения проблемы - убрать автогенерацию и задавать ключи вручную. Вообще, рекомендую ключи делать строковые, например получая их так `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`. У численных идентификаторов есть некоторое количество подводных камней.